# How do I create a nice one dimensional graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"labels": ["This is a long label", 
                     "And this is also a long label", 
                     "Wow its a label thats pretty long", 
                     "Can you follow the pattern here?"],
                   "values": [2.2, 1.2, 3.0, 4.1]})
```

In the real example I have about 15 labels and values. Given this I would like to display a single axis, marks at 2.2, 1.2, 3.0 and 4.1, each labeled with the corresponding label. My labels are long so I think they need to be displayed diagonally or with some other kind of device so the labels remain legible.

#### Clarification

To be clear I want a single axis and no graph field. It will be like a number line, with ticks on it for the values -- 2.2, 1.2, etc. And the labels annotating what the tics stand for.

Here's a very rough sketch of the idea: [image]

I am experimenting but have not found a way to do this pandas or seaborn. Is it even possible?

Comment: could you add a visual of what you're trying to achieve, even something scribbled that you photograph with your phone will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plot a scatter plot, hide the spines & x-axis use the annotate function to place the text. Finally, play with the positioning until the alignment seems right

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.scatter([0]*len(df), df['values'], marker='d', s=100, c='r')
ax.set_xlim(-0.1,5)
for _, r in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(r['labels'], xy=(0.20, r['values']))
```

[image: vertical number line]

Comment: Beautiful! One thing I am trying to figure out... You are using the length of df as the length of the axis but that's not exactly right. I could have 10 points in the range 0-5, or 3 points in the range 0-100.

Comment: i'm not using `len(df)` as the length of the axis. since I'm plotting a scatter along the y-axis, i need to pair each y-value with a x=0. since there are `len(df)` y-values to mark, i need the x-vector to be `[0]*len(df)`

Comment: Oh, right, I misread that. So where does the length of the axis get set to 0-5? I added a row to the df and it ended up extending the length of the displayed axis. I am not sure. And changing the set_xlim() to 0,10 didn't give me a longer axis which is what I expected... Thanks!

Comment: the y-axis limits got set implicitly based on the data. you can set it explicitly using `set_ylim`. I set the x-axis limits as `(0, 5)` so that the origin aligns with the left-spine where the tick labels are positioned.

Comment: Wow, I’m impressed!